# link_to works, but not button_to with parameter to pass

Tags: ruby

I have a link_to that i am trying to convert into a button. But not sure how to pass parameter plan_id in the button_to call. As per the other threads on this, i have used the :get method inside the button_to call.

Works:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_subscription_path(:plan_id => plan.id) %>
```

Does not get plan_id passed :

```
<%= button_to "Sign up", new_subscription_path(:plan_id => plan.id) , :class => "btn btn-primary  btn-large", :method => :get %>
```

Please can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to "Sign up",new_subscription_path(:plan_id => plan.id),{ class:"btn btn-primary btn-large"} %>
```

It will just make the link look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

[button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) has a different syntax, try

```
<%= button_to "Sign up",
             { controller: :subscriptions, action: :new, plan_id: plan.id, method: :get },
             { class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" } %>
```

Comment: It does not recognize the subscriptions controller. I have been trying so many combos all day. Ruby syntax is too esoteric for me.